# "Me knowing that he was... " Is "me" the subject?

Tags: grammaticality, subjects, appositives

> "That was it," he told me. "Laughing at me behind their faces, about a
>   woman. **Me knowing that he was up there**, and them knowing I knew that
>   if I busted in and dragged him out and bashed his head off, I'd not
>   only be cashiered, I'd be clinked for life for having infringed the
>   articles of alliance by invading foreign property without warrant or
>   something."

What is the subject of the sentence starting "Me knowing"? Is this grammatically correct? If it is, why?

It is from "All the Dead Pilots" by William Faulkner.

Comment: The absolute participle construction "Me knowing + that-clause"  has the meaning "I knew + that-clause".

Comment: @rogermue That was my first impression, which would be apt for "Me knowing the facts, I would have been cashiered."  But the cashiered part is the apodosis to the protasis "if I busted in ....", which is too grammatically related for a simple absolute.   And in any case, it's not the first person "knowing I knew"; it's the third.

Comment: *learn_92 There is no subject: see my answer for a reason.

Comment: @rogermue I'd argue for 'The situation was (where licensed) / being (where licensed) that I knew  ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  - Yes, there are several ways to explain those participle constructions.

Comment: You'd have to have an unusual definition of sentence for this to qualify. But the rule 'it is a mortal sin to use anything but a traditional sentence' is actually only a rule of thumb (and here, over-dramatised).

Comment: Note that, traditionally, absolute constructions use the nominative in English (unlike in most other languages I know), which would be ***I** knowing that...and **they** knowing...*

Comment: @Cerberus The _them knowing_ clause is a subordinate one, it's the second of two coordinate non-finite clauses. There is no grammatical sentence because there is no main clause The clause _I'd not only be cashiered, I'd be clinked for life for having infringed the articles of alliance by invading foreign property without warrant or something_ is merely the apodosis of the conditional clause, which crucially is **non-finite** so it can't be a main clause. I had to read it several times before the 'penny dropped'.

Comment: @BillJ: You're right, I applogize. There is no main clause; it is a sentence fragment, not a full sentence. I have voted for your answer now. (Note to posterity: the *which* in Bill's comment above refers to *the apodosis*, not to *the conditional clause*.)

Answer (score 8):

The 'sentence' you asked about has no overall subject. It’s an example of artistic license where the rules of grammar get broken, not due to grammatical incompetence, but for some literary reason, typically resulting in fragments of a sentence being used, as your quote demonstrates.

The result here is that the sequence you asked about is not actually a full sentence, but a coordination of two non-finite clauses:

1. *Me knowing that he was up there*.
2. *Them knowing I knew that if I busted in and dragged him out and bashed his head off, I'd not only be cashiered, I'd be clinked for life for having infringed the articles of alliance by invading foreign property without warrant or something.*

Because there is no main clause, there is no overall grammatical subject.

Comment: @Cerberus Because I misread it initially. "I" is subject of the apodosis, i.e. the second subordinate clause. There is no main clause for the subordinate clauses to latch onto, and hence no overall grammatical subject.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right! I mistakenly went by the punctuation (which I would consider incorrect) and misread it. There is no main clause. I don't know why I didn't get it when I first read your answer.

Comment: @Cerberus Crucially, the protasis is non-finite, so it can't be a main clause,

Comment: By protasis you mean the whole sentence? Because, formally, I only see one protasis, the *if* clause. Or did you mean that the apodosis is dependent? I think that's what you mean, as in your other comment.

Comment: @BillJ What is your opinion on Deadrat's answer? I think the answer is close.

Comment: @Cerberus No, just the sequence from "if" to off".

Comment: @Rathony  He makes some good points, but I concentrated on the fact that there was no main clause, though at first glance the clause _I'd be clinked for life ..._ looks like one, whereas in fact it's only the apodosis for a non-finite protasis. I think between us, we came to the right conclusion. Tricky one, though.

Comment: @BillJ I agree.

Answer (score 5):

Note that I've expanded the quote to include some more context to make it clear that Faulkner is quoting someone relating an incident.  Faulkner is reproducing the patterns of somewhat-convoluted speech.  The main clause of the direct speech is

> That was it

which is followed by two fragments punctuated like sentences that form an appositive to "it," that is naming the situation that "it" refers to.  The two fragments are

> [Their] Laughing at me

and

> Me knowing ..., and them knowing ....

The antecedent to the understood [*Their*] and the explicitly-stated *them* is a roomful of French soldiers mentioned previously. The object of what they know is the clause

> that if I busted ... dragged ... and bashed, [then] I would not only be cashiered ... [but also] clinked

which I've simplified by ellipsis. It takes Faulkner four prepositional phrases to describe what would get the speaker "clinked for life" (i.e., imprisoned for life).

Is it grammatical?  Not strictly, but that often happens with the spoken word, which is what Faulkner has incorporated into his story.  And it doesn't matter much if you've won a Nobel Prize for literature.

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site.  Ya got a problem with the answer but don't have the common courtesy to say what it is?  Fine.  But try to remember that you also mislead the people looking for answers.

Comment: Hi, Deadrat. I fixed one typo. I don't understand why your post received a downvote, but...

Comment: @Rathony Thanks for the fix.  I hate DBDVs (and not just when I'm the target).  They leave the impression that correct answers are wrong, and they leave wrong answers uncorrected.

Comment: I DB-DV very rarely (in fact, I've UV'd here), but understand why people do it: the unwarranted flak. Which can lead to a futile exercise in justifying one's stance.

Comment: I initially misread the sentence. You and Bill are right. The quickest way to convince readers might be to immediately mention that, "contrary to what one would expect, *I'd not only be cashiered...* is not the main clause of the sentence, but it is dependent on *I knew that*...". Because the punctuation of the sentence is i.m.o. incorrect, it is easy to misinterpret the construction of the sentence for a casual reader (which you might also want to mention).

Comment: Now I understand why there was a DB-DV. The sentence is as confusing as it gets. But I think your answer is the closest.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've never understood the unwarranted flak explanation.  How terrible can this be?  After all, no one actually has to participate in a comment thread.  A downvote means the downvoter found the answer unhelpful, which opinion the the holder should justify.  I'd accept "I couldn't follow your answer, and I'm not sure why."  In fact, I can see why that might apply here.  I like BillJ's answer better than mine, enough so that I upvoted his.

Comment: I'm sure that some of the comments are damaging to the site's reputation and thus perceived reliability (which is surely why we have the downvoting etc structures). Recently, there was a confrontational challenge to a close-vote, when the question was more about mathematical jargon, and when the question was duly closed for that reason.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is an entirely different issue.  What I'm talking about is the free pass given to DBDVers a priori on the grounds that they *might* encounter a confrontational challenge to an explanation of their votes.  You're talking about comment threads that *actually* get out of hand.  Although I suspect that even the most blistering comments do less damage to the site's reputation than the routine rudeness to low-rep users.  (And, come to think of it, I don't see how rude comments reflect on the reliability of answers.)

Comment: What is it that you feel is “not strictly grammatical” here?

Comment: @tchrist The narration is in three sentence fragments.

Comment: Ok sentence fragments then. But grammatical ones, correct? Like these?

Comment: @tchrist Ya wanna be That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word About Everything?  Including the meaning of the word *strictly*?  Fine; you're it.  'Cause I don't like it when I turn out to be that guy, which happens more than I care to admit.

Comment: +1 From me. But: "And it doesn't matter much if you've won a Nobel Prize for literature". Hold on a minute, didn't Bob Geldof win a nobel prize for literature? Oh, erm, no, hold on a minute, that was Bob Dylan.  Ok, so anyway, I hope you're not stressing out too much this evening/night/day.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks. Does curled up in the fetal position whimpering uncontrollably count as stressed out?

Comment: @deadrat Given the state of things, I think that might count as remarkably composed ...  [This gave me a little comfort](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-elections/exit-poll-results-latest-us-election-clinton-president-hillary-donald-trump-a7405586.html) whilst I was trying to make a nuclear shelter out of an old matress a bit earlier.

Comment: @deadrat Hope you're not still fetal, although I maybe would be. Don't let orange things break your spirit. Keep rocking in the free world.

Comment: @Araucaria It's hard enough rocking at all at my age, especially when it seems that almost half the country prefers fascism to democracy. This is the last free election I expect to see. I don't mean that elections won't be held. It's just that the folks in charge will use the law to suppress their opponents' ability to vote. Eventually death and demographics will change things, but not in my lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

If you see "me knowing" and "them knowing" as a with-construction (with me knowing, with them knowing") you can very well see "me" and "them" as logical subjects. In with-constructions "with" can be dropped.

Comment: Logical subject of what? The sentence has no main clause, just two subordinate clauses functioning as adjuncts.

Comment: I can't work with all the children crying. If you change the with-construction you get a clause as "when all the children cry/are crying. "The children" becomes the subject,  and the participle becomes the verb of the clause.